# Model property value is not changing from html checkbox in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, model-binding

Razor code-

```
@model SkyTracker.Models.Person

<form method="post" action="Edit">
     @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=> m.IsActive, new {@Value=Model.IsActive })
     <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

Controller code-

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Person person)
{
   var status = person.IsActive; //its always false.
}
```

Whether checkbox is checked or unchecked, model property always remains false.

What did I miss here?

Comment: Change your `@Value`  to `@checked` then you will get the value.

Comment: First remove `new { @Value = Model.IsActive }` (the method sets the value correctly and you should never override the `value` attribute when using a `HtmlHelper` method). If the initial value of `false` then your setting `value="False"` so that is what will be submitted when the checkbox is checked (and do not use `@checked`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoudn't do it like that:

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=> m.IsActive, new {@Value=Model.IsActive })
```

Correct way is:

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=> m.IsActive)
```

asp.net mvc automatically will mark it as checked/unchecked depends on model value

Answer (score 1):

But will it also set the model accordingly? I currently have the same issue and my model value is always true, no  matter if checked or not:

Model:

```
   [DisplayName("AdBlue")]
    public Boolean AdBlue { get; set; }
```

View:

```
    @model Contract.CreateViewModel
    ...

  @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.AdBlue, new { onChange = "GetMasterData()" })
```

When the GetMasterData function is triggered (which is defined in an external JS file, it does this:

```
var AdBlueSelector = document.getElementById("AdBlue").value;
```

But the value of document.getElementById("AdBlue").value is always true, even when the checkbox is not selected. What's wrong with my code?

And when I add a hiddenfield to my view, then the value is always true:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="AdBlue" />
```

Edit: arggh, I just found the error:

```
document.getElementById("AdBlue").value
```

had to be changed to

```
document.getElementById("AdBlue").checked;
```